# Combinatorial Summation of $ \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} {\frac{1}{2^{2n}}} \cos{2n\theta} $.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients

$$ \displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} {\frac{1}{2^{2n}}} \cos{2n\theta} $$

---

**My Approach :**

I rewrote it as $ \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} \left ( {\frac{e^{i\theta}}{2}} \right ) 
 ^{\displaystyle ^{2n}}  $  and need to find it's real component. But I have no idea to how to proceed with it.

I would prefer a hint, no solutions.

---

**Edit :** Can it be simplified more ?

[image]

Comment: Hint: let $q = (\exp(i\theta)/2)^2$. Can you find a "nice" expression for the sum in this case?

Comment: Ok, I will check it out.

Comment: Yes it is coefficient of $\displaystyle q^n$ in $\displaystyle \left ( 1 + q \right ) ^{2n}$.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Thank you I will proceed with this further.

Comment: In case you later need a further hint, here's one: look up the Catalan number generating function.

Comment: Ok, I will check it out.

Comment: You can consider $\sum \binom{2n}{n} z^n$ then it would be useful

Comment: @openspace, Thank you.

Comment: I have edited my work, and now I am stuck on with the final expression. Can it be simplified more ?

Comment: Or I might be committing a mistake, please check my work, I have tried it a lot of times, but same answer all the time.

Comment: Please post your work using MathJax instead of photos.  MathJax can be searched, unlike a photo, and is also more legible.  For a tutorial, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference .

Comment: @awkward, Thank you for informing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Catalan generating function $\sum_{n\ge0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{x^n}{n+1}=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}$. Applying $f\mapsto (xf)^\prime$, $\sum_{n\ge0}\binom{2n}{n}x^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}$. (This can also be proven with the generalized binomial theorem). So$$\sum_{n\ge0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{\cos2n\theta}{2^{2n}}=\Re\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-e^{2i\theta}}}=\Re\frac{1}{\sqrt{-2i\sin\theta e^{i\theta}}}.$$If $\sin\theta>0$, this is$$\Re\frac{\exp i(\pi/4-\theta/2)}{\sqrt{2\sin\theta}}=\frac{\cos(\pi/4-\theta/2)}{\sqrt{2\sin\theta}}.$$If $\sin\theta<0$, we instead get $\frac{\cos(-\pi/4-\theta/2)}{\sqrt{-2\sin\theta}}$. We can combine these as $\frac{\cos\left(\pi/4-\tfrac{\theta}{2}\operatorname{sgn}\sin\theta\right)}{\sqrt{2|\sin\theta|}}$.

Comment: Is $\displaystyle C_n = \frac {1}{n+1} \binom {2n}{n} $ or $\displaystyle C_n = \frac {1}{n} \binom {2n-2}{n-1} $ ?

Comment: In books it is given as $\displaystyle C_n = \frac {1}{n} \binom {2n-2}{n-1} $

Comment: Also , $\displaystyle C(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} C_n \cdot x^n $  Here $C_n $ will matter.

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi I'm using the former convention, which makes the stated generating function correct. Whatever book gave you that formula for $C_n$, it won't work at $n=0$.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking this too. Means former convention is which you mentioned....

Comment: @NikolaAlfredi In other words, multiply by $x$, then differentiate with respect to $x$. (I could have equivalently said, "differentiate with respect to $\ln x$".)

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it another way and it looks simpler: [image]

But is this correct ?

Comment: If it is right then did I committed a mistake in my EDIT , in the question?